# How to separate path from a filename

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a path to a file like:

> C:\NewFolder\Test\file1.doc

How do I remove the filename from the path .I require only

> C:\NewFolder\Test\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

```
var path = @"C:\NewFolder\Test\file1.doc";

var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

`System.IO.Path` is full of awesome useful stuff like this, I encourage you to take a look!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\NewFolder\Test\file1.doc")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\NewFolder\Test\file1.doc");
```

check here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileInfo.Directory:

```
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo("C:\NewFolder\Test\file1.doc");
var directoryInfo = myFile.Directory;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using System.IO; Check out the [the Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx). Specifically [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).